# Django raw query giving same result on all models

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 3 models `Product, Photo, and ProductLikeDilike`. I am performing left outer join on all the 3 models. First I am joining `Product` with `Photo` and then the resultant table(`temp`) I am joining with `ProductLikeDilike`. Below is the raw sql.

**Note**: `olx` is the name of django app.

```
data = Product.objects.raw('select * from (select 
    olx_product.id,olx_product.name,olx_photo.file,olx_photo.cover_photo_flag 
    from olx_product left outer join olx_photo on 
    (olx_product.id=olx_photo.reference_id_id) where 
    olx_photo.cover_photo_flag="yes" or olx_photo.cover_photo_flag is null) as 
    temp left outer join olx_productlikedislike on 
    (temp.id=olx_productlikedislike.product_id_id and 
    olx_productlikedislike.product_liked_by_id_id=2)')

for x in data:
  print(x.name)
```

What I want to understand that when I use any of the above 3 models to run the raw sql why I am getting the same result i.e.

When I do

```
data = Product.objects.raw('select *.....')
for x in data:
  print(x.name)
```

or

```
data = Photo.objects.raw('select *......') 
for x in data:
  print(x.name)
```

or

```
data = ProductLikeDislike.raw('select *.....')
for x in data:
  print(x.name)
```

I am getting the same result. Why?
Please help me to understand this.

Below is the models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



    class Product(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, db_index = True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 200, db_index = True)     
        description = models.TextField(blank = True)    
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2 )#Not used FloatField to avoid rounding issues
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

        contact= models.BigIntegerField(default=None,blank=True, null=True)
        created_by = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default=None,blank=True, null=True)
        uploaded_by_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        status = models.IntegerField(default=0) # 0-->Active,1-->Inactive
        mark_as_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0) # 0-->not sold,1-->sold

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('olx:edit_product', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})



        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-created',)
            index_together = (('id','slug'),)# we want to query product by id and slug using together index to improve performance

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


    class Photo(models.Model):

        reference_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
        photo_type = models.CharField(max_length = 70, db_index = True)
        file = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/',default='NoImage.jpg')
        cover_photo_flag = models.CharField(default=0,max_length = 5, db_index = True)
        uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        uploaded_by_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        status = models.IntegerField(default=0) # 0-->Active,1-->Inactive



        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-uploaded_at',)


    class ProductLikeDislike(models.Model):
        product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product,models.SET_DEFAULT,default=0) 
        product_liked_by_id = models.ForeignKey(User,models.SET_DEFAULT,default=0) 
        status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And Please also show me how to write it in pure Django way if possible?

Comment: Because you are making same `SQL` query everywhere.

Comment: Why wouldn't you get that? You only have one name field, and that is what is being displayed.

Comment: What I am thinking is that in my raw sql I am using 3 different tables but I am calling Django's raw method on only one model(Product or Photo or ProductLikeDilike) so how the django is executing this?

Comment: Instead of downvoting my question try to understand and answer it properly as per my last comment.

Comment: @chiragsoni: `.raw(..)` will from any model always do the same query. Typically you aim to do a very limited (well none at all) raw queries, and use the ORM to construct the query.

Comment: thanks willem please show me the django orm way to do it and if possible also show me the document that `.raw(..)` will always do the same query.

Comment: Hi willem I am completely agree with your point that `.raw(..)` will always do the same query from any model I checked just now So basically I got the answer for the question I posted. Now please help me in writing the above big query in Django way.

Comment: @chiragsoni: can you share the relevant models?

Comment: sure william I am sharing

Comment: see I am editing question to have models.py file

Comment: This is neither here nor there, but `product_id` and `reference_id` should NEVER be used as model properties.

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion going forward I will not use like this but with product_id and reference_id it is working fine when I just joint Product and Photo model

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    user_i_care_about = User.objects.get(username='user2')
    productlikedislike_set = models.Prefetch('productlikedislike_set',
                                             ProductLikeDislike.objects.select_related('product_liked_by') \
                                                               .filter(product_liked_by=user_i_care_about) \
                                                               .order_by('id'))
    photo_set = models.Prefetch('photo_set', Photo.objects.all())  # this is here incase you need to a select_related()

    products = Product.objects.prefetch_related(photo_set, productlikedislike_set) \
                              .filter(models.Q(photo__cover_photo_flag='yes') | models.Q(photo__isnull=True)) \
                              .filter(productlikedislike__product_liked_by=user_i_care_about)
```

Then you can use:

```
for product in products:
    for pic in product.photo_set.all():
        print(x.file.name)
    # every product here WILL be liked by the user
```

if your models look something like this:

```
 class Product(models.Model):
    # category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # TODO: uncomment, didnt want to model this out
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)  # Not used FloatField to avoid rounding issues  # this is correct, no need to explain this, anyonw that works with django, gets this.
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    contact = models.BigIntegerField(default=None,blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    uploaded_by_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # TODO: use ForeignKey(User) here!!!
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # 0-->Active,1-->Inactive  # TODO: learn to use `choices`
    mark_as_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # 0-->not sold,1-->sold  # TODO: there is something called `BooleanField` use it!

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)  # we want to query product by id and slug using together index to improve performance

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('olx:edit_product', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Photo(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='reference_id')
    photo_type = models.CharField(max_length=70, db_index=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/', default='NoImage.jpg')
    cover_photo_flag = models.CharField(default=0, max_length=5, db_index=True)  # TODO: learn to use `choices`, and you use "yes" / "no" -- and the default is 0 -- FIX THIS!!
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uploaded_by_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # TODO: use ForeignKey(User) here!!!
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # 0-->Active,1-->Inactive  # TODO: learn to use `choices` -- perhaps just call this "is_active" and make it a bool

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-uploaded_at',)


class ProductLikeDislike(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.SET_DEFAULT, default=0)  # TODO: default=0?? this is pretty bad. models.ForeignKey(Product, models.SET_NULL, null=True) is much better
    product_liked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_DEFAULT, default=0, db_column='product_liked_by_id')  # TODO: default=0?? this is pretty bad. models.ForeignKey(ForeignKey, models.SET_NULL, null=True) is much better
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # TODO: rename, bad name. try something like "liked" / "disliked" OR go with IntegerField(choices=((0, 'Liked'), (1, 'Disliked')) if you have more than 2 values.
```

A full example WITH tests can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/05ed095d8f48c3904e217e56235af54a

Comment: Let me check by running this

Comment: bro it is giving me empty queryset:<QuerySet []>

Comment: Hi Javier could you little bit improve your answer because from your answer it looks like you're at corner just a subtle change in it will give the correct answer to me.

Comment: With the suggested answer I tried but giving the empty queryset. So please analyse it again.

Comment: @chiragsoni ive updated my answer, since you updated your models. Also, can you post your models in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and link me, there are some glaring issues with it, i'll walk you through how to fix them.

Comment: models.py file is there in the posted question.

Comment: can I post the exactly same question there?

Comment: @chiragsoni its code review, so put the code, the question is irrelevant.

Comment: @chiragsoni does the query i gave you solve your issue?

Comment: Hi, bro, I tried your query it is giving me 12 records but it should have given 16, that my raw query is giving, so I analyzed yours by printing it as `print(products.query)` I found that why it is giving 12 records becayse it is inner joining productlikedislike model but actually we need to left joint it as I showed in my raw query, see question. so do little changes.

Comment: Anyway bro great effort you are doing. Below is the raw query I got  from your Django query:

Comment: Sorry I am not able to post here it is too long.

Comment: Bro is it good to write custom sql query using cursor like this:                                                                                                   `from django.db import connection`                                                              
 `cursor = connection.cursor()`                                                                                        
  `cursor.execute('select ....')`   in production.

Comment: Javier I wrote very simplest query to  achieve it but I have a little problem can you please chat with me to workaround that. If you are gree then please send me a chat invite as I have less score I can not initiate that. Please....

Comment: @chiragsoni look here, https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/05ed095d8f48c3904e217e56235af54a#file-otc-py-L160 can you update your answer with the equivalent of lines 160-175 of YOUR data. That way i can see what it is youre actually trying to query. With the data i fabricated looks good.

Comment: I found a very simple way of doing it. But I have a little doubt please do chat with me.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting the same result. Why? Please help me to understand this.

Because [**`.raw(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#raw) just takes a raw query and executes it. The model from which the raw is performed is irrelevant.

We can generate a query that looks like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Product.objects.filter(
    Q(photo__photo_flag__isnull=True) | Q(photo__photo_flag='yes'),
    Q(likedislike__product_liked_by_id_id=2)
)
```

So here we accept all `Product`s for which a related `Photo` object has a `flag` that is `NULL` (this also happens in case the JOIN does not yield any flags), or the `photo_flag` is `'yes'`). Furthermore there should be a `Likedislike` object where the `liked_by_id_id` is `2`.

Note that usually a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) has *no* `_id` suffix, or `id_` prefix. It is also a bit "odd" that you set a `default=0` for this, especially since most databases only assign *strictly* positive values as primary keys, and it makes no sense to inherently prefer `0` over another object anyway.

Comment: I ran this query:`Product.objects.filter(Q(photo__cover_photo_flag__isnull=True) | Q(photo__cover_photo_flag='yes'),Q(productlikedislike__product_liked_by_id_id=2)).select_related('photo')` but getting the error:`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'photo'. Choices are: category`

Comment: because the `Product` modal has

Comment: @chiragsoni: ah yes, since you did the foreign key in reverse, you can indeed not `.select_relate(..)` it.

Comment: Because the `Product` modal has `category` as ForeignKey not the `photo` as ForeignKey while `Photo` modal has product as ForeignKey which I named as `reference_id` see my models.py file

Comment: Hi william bro any suggestion?

Comment: Bro is it good to write custom sql query using cursor like this: `from django.db import connection`  `cursor = connection.cursor()`  `cursor.execute('select ....')`  in production.

Comment: Willem I wrote very simplest query to  achieve it but I have a little problem can you please chat with me to workaround that. If you are gree then please send me a chat invite as I have less score I can not initiate that. Please....

Comment: @chiragsoni: please don't use raw queries, these will not be updated when you change your model(s), etc. What exactly is not working with the above approach?

Comment: Ok thanks willem I got the left join but I have little problem can you please help me

Comment: Can you please come over chat?

Comment: willem please come here:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194328/discussion-between-omar-and-qux